# I need to know how to configure script in atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I want to edit python with atom and be able to run script. But when I do it says that python is not an external or internal command. I know what the problem is that when I search command prompt for the version of python is says "command not found" I have to search py --version. so I've read in the forums that I need to configure the script package but I don't know what to do after clicking on configure script.